# Run complex program from USB drive without chroot

Tags: usb, qemu

I am creating a portable USB drive that has a Windows VM on it so I can run my Windows games on any computer. I am using QEMU as my virtual machine program because it is portable, multiplatform, and does not require me to have admin access. I have gotten it to work successfully on Windows, but I'm having trouble getting it to work on Linux and Mac machines (which are the ones I am probably going to use this on the most) because of missing libraries. I cannot use a chroot because the disk image is in a directory above the jails, and chroot also requires root permission to run, which I may not have on the computer. How can I run a program that requires extra libraries without chroot?

Comment: What libraries are missing? Seems like those "missing" libraries are provided by the host Windows system.

Comment: You will need to put the linux and osx libs on the usb or you will need to download a portable version of qemu for linux and osx. Typically the portable qemu have the windows lib and exe portable and assume you have qemu installed on linux. See https://www.maketecheasier.com/transform-gedit-into-a-web-developer-ide/  .   See https://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/?q=portable+qemu and https://sourceforge.net/projects/qemuportable/?source=directory . I have not tried them , typically I have qemu installed on Linux.

Comment: To be honest, Virtualbox is faster - http://www.vbox.me/ , but does require administrative rights. If you go with qeum you will want a lighter OS (Tinycore) to improve performance.

Comment: There is a thread here with suggestions to make qemu portable with linux libs https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14135/install-virtual-machine-as-non-root

Comment: @jpezz I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the library folder in the QEMU install folder, and used the -L flag to specify a path to the BIOS/ROM files, but now it needs the ROM for device e1000. Seems like library-wise it's fine now, though ROM files are still needed.